# Hiding "Group By" value in a Content Query Web part

Tags: sharepoint, hide, field

I'm making a Sharepoint 2007 Content Query web part, where I want to group by a field (ArticleSticky), but I don't want to show the field in the webpart. 
Is there some way I can hide the field in the webpart? Maybe in the XSLT definition ?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, you probably want to add a custom header style in the style library.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with some JavaScript.
Here is an example using JQuery:

```
$(function() {  
    $("table.ms-listviewtable td.ms-gb").each(function(){
      $(this).find("a:eq(2)").replaceWith($(this).find("a:eq(2)").text()) 
    }) 
});
```